# Algorithm: ELSEIF problem

Tags: algorithms

I want to compile this code in Latex (shown below). I use three libraries. I especially need `elseif` and `\state` command and `line number`.

LaTeX Error:

```
Command \algorithmicindent already defined.Or name \end... illegal,
see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for
explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help....
\newlength{\algorithmicindent}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Offloading decision}\label{offloading_decision_pseudocode}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Known: Smartphone to Edge Cloud and Smartphone to Core Cloud bandwidth,
smartphone to Edge Cloud and smartphone to Core Cloud RTT,
smartphone and Edge/Core Cloud processor speed,
Edge and Core Cloud processing cost
\State Set weights $w1$, $w2$, $w3$ based on user preferences 
\State Estimate $T_{L}$, $T_{R-edge}$, $T_{R-Core}$ (section \ref{estimate_processing_time})
\State Estimate $E_{L}$, $E_{R-edge}$, $E_{R-Core}$ (section \ref{estimate_energy_consumption})
\State Estimate $C_{L}$, $C_{R-edge}$, $C_{R-Core}$ (section \ref{estimate_processing_cost})
\State Compute $P_{s}$, $P_{E}$, $P_{C}$ 
\If {$P_{s}\: is\: maximum $} 
    \State
     \ElseIf {$P_{E}$ is maximum}
\EndIf
\If {$i > \textit{stringlen}$} \Return false
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `ElsIf{}` and not `ElseIf{}`

Comment: Also: use `\usepackage{algorithmicx}`

Answer (score 3):

1. The `algpseudocode` package defines the command `\ElsIf` and not `\ElseIF`
2. As  noticed by @DG' remove `\usepackage{algoritmic}`
3. If you use `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` you don't have to call `\usepackage{algortihmicx}` explicitly 
   !

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}
    %\usepackage{algorithmic}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{algorithm}
   \caption{Offloading decision}\label{offloading_decision_pseudocode}
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \State Known: Smartphone to Edge Cloud and Smartphone to Core Cloud bandwidth,
   smartphone to Edge Cloud and smartphone to Core Cloud RTT,
   smartphone and Edge/Core Cloud processor speed,
   Edge and Core Cloud processing cost
   \State Set weights $w1$, $w2$, $w3$ based on user preferences 
   \State Estimate $T_{L}$, $T_{R-edge}$, $T_{R-Core}$ (section \ref{estimate_processing_time})
   \State Estimate $E_{L}$, $E_{R-edge}$, $E_{R-Core}$ (section \ref{estimate_energy_consumption})
   \State Estimate $C_{L}$, $C_{R-edge}$, $C_{R-Core}$ (section \ref{estimate_processing_cost})
   \State Compute $P_{s}$, $P_{E}$, $P_{C}$ 
   \If {$P_{s}\: is\: maximum $} 
       \State
        \ElsIf {$P_{E}$ is maximum}
   \EndIf
   \If {$i > \textit{stringlen}$} \Return false
   \EndIf
   \State $i \gets i-1$.
   \State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
   \State \textbf{close};
   \State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
   \State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
   \end{algorithmic}
   \end{algorithm}
   \end{document}
   ```